# replace the second point since the end of a line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

How I can replace the second point since the end of a line?

```
11.22.mail.su => 11.22@mail.su
22.mails.de => 22@mails.de
```

etc.

I'm interested examples for `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: The TLD is not guaranteed to be the second level. In fact, some country toplevel domains force it to be the third level (au, nz, etc; some like uk only recently began to permit a restricted second level IIRC) and there are hierarchies much deeper than that (k12.<state>.us, for example; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.us is interesting reading).

Answer (score 3):

As far as `sed`, try this:

```
sed -e 's/\.\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)$/@\1/'
```

So:

```
# echo "11.22.mail.su" | sed -e 's/\.\([^\.]*\.[^\.]*\)$/@\1/g'
11.22@mail.su
# echo "22.mails.de" | sed -e 's/\.\([^\.]*\.[^\.]*\)$/@\1/g'
22@mails.de
```

Comment: No need for g (global!) There is 1 char to replace.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ $0 = gensub( /\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$/, "@\\1", 1 ); print }' infile
```

Output:

```
11.22@mail.su
22@mails.de
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\.\)/\1@\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure-bash solution (not that I would recommend using it, and the individual steps could be combined if desired):

```
# An extended pattern to match a single field. letters, numbers, and a hyphen
# Add characters if necessary
shopt -s extglob
field='+([[:alnum:]-])'   

for foo in 11.22.mail.su 22.mails.de; do

    # The first part: drop the last two fields and the dots that precede them
    first="${foo%.$field.$field}"

    # The first part, followed by the @, followed by the full string minus the first
    # part and its following dot.
    modified="$first@${foo/#$first.}"

done
```

A little better would be to use bash's regular expression support.

```
for foo in 11.22.mail.su 22.mails.de; do
    [[ $foo =~ (.*)\.([^.]+\.[^.]+) ]]
    # Three ways to join the two halves with @ 
    one_way="$BASH_REMATCH[1]@${BASH_REMATCH[2]}

    printf -v second_way "%s@%s" ${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:2}

    SAVE_IFS="$IFS"
    IFS="@"
    third_way="@{BASH_REMATCH[*]:1:2}"
    IFS="$SAVE_IFS"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a second to see what you're doing. Just a reminder, this is a valid email address:

```
bob@mail.server.com
```

And so is this:

```
bob.smith@mail.server.com
```

You said replace the second period from the *end of the line*. That means your regular expression should be anchored to the end of the line. A `$` at the end of a regular expression does just that.

Let's take a look at your example:

```
11.22.mail.su
```

You want to match `.mail.su`. Let's start with the last character which would be the `$`. We can represent any combination of characters by doing `.*`. This represents any string from zero to the length of the line. The period represents any character, and the `*` represents zero or more of the preceding.

The period is a special regular expression character, so we need to put a backslash in front of it in order to be a period: `\.`. So far so good.

This should work:

```
\..*\..*$
```

And, putting parentheses around what we want to match:

```
(\.)(.*)(\.)(.*)$
```

There! The first (.) captures the second to the last period. The next `(.*)` captures zero or more characters, the third one captures, `(.*)` captures the rest of the line, and the `$` anchors it on the end.

Except it doesn't really work because regular expressions are greedy. For example, if I had this as my regular expression:

```
.*###
```

And my string looks like this:

```
first###second###third###fourth
```

That regular expression doesn't capture `first###`. It captures the longest string it can which happens to be `first###second###third###`.

The way around this is to exclude the character you want to match up to. In this case, we don't want to match on a `#`. Therefore, we can do this:

```
[^#]*###
```

And that will match only `first###`. The `[^#]` says any character ***except*** the `#`. The `*` means zero or more non-# characters. So, I'm going to replace the `.*` in my above expressions to `[^.]` which means any character except the period.

Before:

```
(\.)(.*)(\.)(.*)$
```

After:

```
(\.)([^.]*)(\.)([^.]*)$
```

See the difference in the second and fourth grouping?

One more little issue: In `sed`, which is what I'm using, you have to put a backslash in front of the parentheses, or else they're really just the character `(` and `)` in the string. This is the only character you have to put a backslash in front of in order to make it magical. Every other magical regular expression character is magical until you put a backslash in front of it. This means instead of this:

```
(\.)([^.]*)(\.)([^.]*)$
```

We need to do this:

```
\(\.\)\([^.]*\)\(\.\)\([^.]*\)$
```

Same as above, but now with a backslash before each opening and closing parentheses.

Now, we have something that will match the end of your string, let's do the substitution. First, a simple test:

```
$ echo "11.22.mail.su" | sed 's/\(\.\)\([^.]*\)\(\.\)\([^.]*\)$/FOO/'
11.12FOO
```

Yup, that matches the end. Next, we can refer to a grouping by putting a backslash in front of the group number:

```
$ echo "11.22.mail.su" | sed 's/\(\.\)\([^.]*\)\(\.\)\([^.]*\)$/@\2\3\4/'
11.22@mail.su
```

Perfect. Note that the first group is my first period. I replace that with an `@`. Next, I want to keep the second, third, and fourth group. Thus, my replacement string is `@\2\3\4`.

By the way, I don't really need four groupings. I could simply match to the period and then put the rest of the line as a single group:

```
echo "11.22.mail.su" | sed 's/\.\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)$/@\1/'
```

Yup, regular expressions are so simple and clear to read! A friend of mine refers to regular expressions as *sailor cussing* because in the old comic strips, when someone lays out a bunch of vulgarities, they use what could be regular expression symbols.<sup>*</sup>

One of the nice features in Perl is that you can break up a regular expression in multiple lines, so you can comment what's going on:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

$string = "11.22.mail.su";
$string =~ s/       #Start of my substitution
\.                  #A period
(                   #Start capturing a string
[^.]*               #Everything up to the next period.
\.                  #The next period
[^.]*)$             #And capture it to the end of the line
/@\1/x;             #Replace with a "@" and the rest of the string

print "String = '$string'\n";

$ test.pl
String = '11.22@mail.su'
```

The other thing nice about Perl is that the parentheses have special meaning **unless** you put a backslash in front of them. (The opposite of `sed`).

---

One thing I sort of mentioned off hand, but didn't really focus on. This `[^.]*` matches ***zero*** or more non-periods. That could be an issue with a regular expression. To get around the problem and to force at least a match of one, you need to double up your regular expression. For example, `[^#]*#FOO` will match `THIS IS A #FOO` and will match just plain `#FOO` too.

If I do this: `[^#][^#]*#FOO` and double up the regular expression, I can guarantee there is at least one non-`#` character before the `#`. That regular expression will match `THIS IS A #FOO`, but not just plain `#FOO`.

So, we might have to go from:

```
$ sed 's/\(\.\)\([^.]*\)\(\.\)\([^.]*\)$/FOO/'
```

to

```
$ sed 's/\(\.\)\([^.][^.]*\)\(\.\)\([^.][^.]*\)$/FOO/'
```